# Haskell Streams (Comonadic): Infinite?

Tags: haskell, stream, lazy-evaluation, infinite

I've seen streams used as the default example of a comonad, but I can't quite figure how they're infinite, but not.

Assume we have the data constructor ([from here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streams-3.3/docs/Data-Stream-Infinite.html))

```
data Stream a = a :> Stream a
```

How do we finally finish off a stream? Do we write it w/ an undefined at the end? I get that the language is lazy, but somewhere the knot must be cut, right? Am I just wrong?

Comment: If you finish it it won't be infinite anymore, huh?

Answer (score 6):

A stream is inherently infinite; you can't create a finite stream. Compare `Stream` and `List`:

```
data List   a = Empty | a :  List a
data Stream a =         a :> Stream a
```

You can create a finite list because of `Empty` constructor; it is possible to create a `List` value without referring to another `List` value. A `Stream` value, on the other hand, can *only* be created by using *another* `Stream` value. *Any* time you pattern match on a `Stream`, you get a value of type `a` and another `Stream` value.

"Finishing" a stream simply means you stop pulling values from it, not that you ever reach the "end" of the stream.

In practice, this means you cannot instantiate a full stream in memory; you can only build it on-demand, typically by calling a function to generate remainder of the stream when pattern matching on the `:>` constructor.

Comment: While denotationally entirely reasonable, the last paragraph (about "instantiat[ing] a full stream in memory") isn't correct operationally – that's exactly what knot-tying gives you!  For example, given the definition `ones = 1 :> ones`, the stream will be represented by a single "cons" cell with a pointer back to itself (once the thunks are gone).

Comment: A more realistic scenario is the stream of keys pressed by the user: you treat this as an infinite stream because there is never a key press that is known to be the last one (ignoring ctrl-D for now). Termination happens when the program ends, not when the stream ends.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky that would work well as an answer. Also, so all streams are circular then?

Comment: @JackBrandt  A loop is the only way to represent a conceptually infinite stream in finite memory (absent any other specific logic).

Comment: @JackBrandt You *can* represent streams in finite memory, through that circular technique.  But you don't have to: the stream `nats = 0 :> fmap (+1) nats` is the infinite stream `0 :> 1 :> 2 :> …`, but it would take infinite memory if you forced the whole thing.  (Unless, of course, you garbage-collected it along the way…)

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky Forcing the stream is what I've been referring to; I just forgot the term.

Comment: Yeah, I was just a little still stuck in non-lazy ways. I just watched some video by George Wilson, in it he features "non-empty lists" which helped me understand streams a lot better.